# Is WebView (EdgeHTML) affected by the libwebp vulnerabilities found lately (CVE-2023-4863)?

Tags: security, webview, webp

A critical vulnerability was recently found in the WebP Codec image rendering library (libwebp).

It appears that [WebView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/controls/wpf-winforms/webview) (based on EdgeHTML) is able to render WebP images.

Question: Does WebView link libwebp directly?
Or does the WebP functionality in WebView rely on some other vulnerable component (e.g. [WebP Image Extension](https://apps.microsoft.com/store/detail/webp-image-extensions/9PG2DK419DRG?hl=en-us&gl=us))?
What would be the remedies in either case?

I know that WebView has been replaced by [WebView2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/), but unfortunately, we still have a few customers which use WebView, and updating them to WebView2 would take too much time given the fact that the vulnerability is already actively exploited.

[EDIT1]: According to [this post](https://www.ctrl.blog/entry/windows-webp-appguard.html), the EdgeHTML based MS Edge application actually relies on WebP Image Extension:

> Support for WebP was implemented as a platform format extension your
> device gets from the [Microsoft Store](https://apps.microsoft.com/store/detail/webp-image-extensions/9PG2DK419DRG) the same way the Theora and
> Vorbis media codecs were added earlier this year. The extensions are
> pushed automatically to Windows 10 users...

I wonder if that also applies to WebView?